# Jumping Vs. Gravity

Tags: c#, xna, physics

I'm working on my first XNA 2D game and I have a little problem.
If I jump, my sprite jumps but does not fall down.
And I also have another problem, the user can hold *spacebar* to jump as high as he wants and I don't know how to keep him from doing that. Here's my code:
The Jump :

```
    if (FaKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            Jumping = true;
            xPosition -= new Vector2(0, 5);
        }

        if (xPosition.Y >= 10)
        {
            Jumping = false;
            Grounded = false;
        }
```

The really simple basic Gravity:

```
    if (!Grounded && !Jumping)
        {
            xPosition += new Vector2(1, 3) * speed;
        }
```

Here's where's the grounded is set to True or False with a Collision

```
    Rectangle MegamanRectangle = new Rectangle((int)xPosition.X, (int)xPosition.Y, FrameSizeDraw.X, FrameSizeDraw.Y);
        Rectangle Block1Rectangle = new Rectangle((int)0, (int)73, Block1.Width, Block1.Height);
        Rectangle Block2Rectangle = new Rectangle((int)500, (int)73, Block2.Width, Block2.Height);

        if ((MegamanRectangle.Intersects(Block1Rectangle) || (MegamanRectangle.Intersects(Block2Rectangle))))
        {
            Grounded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Grounded = false;
        }
```

The grounded bool and The gravity have been tested and are working.
Any ideas why?
Thanks in advance and don't hesitate to ask if you need another Part of the Code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A relatively simple way to handle jumping is to implement gravity as a vector and jumping/moving as an impulse.

For example:

```
foreach (Object obj in GameWorld)
{
    obj.Velocity *= 0.5; // Slow it down slightly
    obj.Velocity += GravityPerSecond * FrameTime; // Gravity adjusted for time
    obj.Move(obj.Velocity); // Handle collision and movement here
}
```

The velocity should be a vector with the same dimensions as the world, and Move a method that moves the object as far as possible in the vector given.

Jump code:

```
OnKeyDown(Key k)
{
    if (k == Key.Space)
    {
        obj.Velocity += Vector2(0, 10); // Add an upward impulse
    }
}
```

This will cause the object to move up for a bit, then begin to fall. You can use similar impulses for other effects (movement, explosions, collision). You will need to have collision modify the velocity when two objects collide, for bouncing.

This is an extremely simple physics system that will make future changes much simpler, and could allow some interesting level design (change gravity and such). It simplifies handling jumping by abstracting it out from complex IsJumping code to a single mechanic.

To prevent jumping without standing on an object, you'd need to do a collision test, or track when objects collide/stop colliding for the down direction. It might also be possible to check if the object's vertical velocity is zero and allow jumping only then (would prevent jumping while falling or moving up).

Comment: I really like this approach! But I'm new to this and can't figure out what to put instead of "GameWorld"

Comment: Whatever you keep your game objects in, be it the world, scene manager, etc. You may want to keep a collection of physics objects (only movable objects, leave out the static level) and use that.

Comment: +1; Good suggestion.  My two cents: Depending on your game, sometimes more fake physics can give you better results.  Ala the mario games, or nearly any NES or SNES era platform game.  You'll have easier calculations/less experimentation when designing your levels, and it won't be as hard to solve some things, like "tunneling", or accidentally making your physics work differently on different machines.  It won't be as general tho.  If you go with a more generalized velocity/acceleration approach like this answer suggests, you might also want to look into modeling terminal velocity.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this might be the answer:

change your

```
    if (FaKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
    {
        Jumping = true;
        xPosition -= new Vector2(0, 5);
    }

    if (xPosition.Y >= 10)
    {
        Jumping = false;
        Grounded = false;
    }
```

to

```
    if (!Jumping && FaKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
    {
        Jumping = true;
        Grounded = false;
    }

    if (Jumping)
    {
        xPosition -= new Vector2(0, 5);
    } 

    if (xPosition.Y >= 10)
    {
        Jumping = false;
    }
```

The other answers given with velocity are really better approaches, but this might be close enough to get you started again.

Comment: You might also use !Jumping rather than Grounded in the conditional statement of the solution if it fits your gravity model better.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work .. The sprite doesn't jump at all.
And if I change xPosition -= new Vector(0, 5) to new Vector (0, 20) or  higher the sprite jumps a little but still doesn't fall .:(
I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very rustic solution to making a jump go up and down:

```
const float SCALE = 20.0f; //SPEED!!!
if (jump <= 15 && jump != 0)
            {
                humanPosition.Y -= SCALE * speed;
                jump++;
            }
            else if (jump > 15)
            {
                humanPosition.Y += SCALE * speed;
                jump++;
                if (jump == 32)
                {
                    jump = 0;
                    humanPosition.Y = 307;
                }
            }
```

And is activated by

```
            else if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            jump = 1;
            humanPosition.Y -= SCALE * speed;
        }
```

What this does is set in motion the jump by setting it to 1
Also if you want to restrict jumping to only when the character is on the ground you can add a condition similar to this

```
if (humanPosition.Y != GROUNDLEVEL){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jumping shouldn't be a boolean unless you need it for something like an animation or an ability that can only be used while jumping.

Instead, you should be using vector movement and when the player is touching the ground and press their jump button, add an upward jump vector to your motion.

Then, gravity needs to be a downward vector acting against the player and it will handle itself.